# How to distinguish the type of transistor amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier

I tutor students studying for an exam where they are likely to be asked to recognise a circuit, with a single transistor, as one of: a) a common base amplifier; b) a common emitter amplifier: c) a common collector amplifier. Is there a mnemonic or other easily remembered way to distinguish them?

Comment: Yes. The named terminal is common to both the input and output circuits, or "grounded" (AC ground : its DC potential is whatever is needed to make the circuit work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CE does not use E as the direct input

CB does not use B as the direct input

CC does not use C as the output

The word "common" means that the pin-name following cannot be either a direct input or an output.

For all three types you can always say B is never an output and C is never an input. Thus CE (for instance) implies the input is at B and the output is at C.

Comment: I would have said "common" refers the subject noun as a shared port or "common" to both "input and output" and thus is neither nor output. But you used reduction logic to the I/O practical uses.

Answer (score 12):

Looking for a mnemonic or some mental hack to distinguish different transistor circuit configurations is the wrong thing to do.  *Think* about it.  What would be the point?  The purpose of naming some common transistor circuits is to quickly communicate them to others, and after some experience, to short-cut some analysis of the circuits.  Simply being able to name a circuit without understanding what that means is pointless.  Teaching students to do that is doing them a disservice.

Instead, they should learn some basics of how bipolar transistors work, and then how they can be used in some common circuits to achieve certain goals.  There is no substitute for actually *understanding* these things.  The fact that some of these circuits are common enough to have standards names should only be a minor point once the understanding has occurred.  After the students work with these common circuits enough, they'll eventually remember their names.

Learning by memorizing mnemonics and half-baked rules of thumb is no learning at all.  Do your job right and teach them what they really need to learn.

Comment: Ok Olin Lathrop, you are right, and that's a nice approach, but my job was and is to get students to pass the exam, and they need the rote approach as well sometimes. so I don't accept the criticism. In the real world they have access to all the reference material. In the exam they are on their own and any legitimate means to help is acceptable in my opinion, after thirty years experience of teaching university students and setting the exams. If they can't pass the exam why take the course, and there are plenty of ways to test their initiative and understanding. and deeper  knowledge.

Comment: @HarryWeston If they don't understand the material, why take the course?

Comment: @Harry: Simply passing a exam should never be the goal.  The goal should be learning, after which passing the exam happens on its own.  Passing exams may work in the short term, but this will catch up with them before too long.  Such students will never be good engineers, and I have no respect for them or their teachers.  I ruthlessly weed them out in interviews by forcing them to show me what they know and can do, not how they answer exam questions.  You might as well teach them to say *"Do you want fries with that?"* now and save them some time and tuition.

Comment: @HarryWeston " In the real world they have access to all the reference material" - but will they be employable in the real world, if they need to look up the spelling of "the" in a dictionary every time they want to write a sentence? Not if I interview them when they apply for a job. And not if they can't identify the input and output of a simple one-transistor amplifier circuit without using a textbook, either!

Comment: Upvoted. there's far too much of this learning of tricks w/o learning the trade in the first place. The root cause is partly a surfeit of credentialism, IMO.

Comment: Well a simple request for a mnemonic has turned into a patronising (and occasionally pompous) castigation of my teaching methods. Of course I teach all that, and I also teach "how to pass an exam without knowing anything", which always goes down well. If you don't teach mnemonics, how do they learn the Resistor Colour Code? Perhaps from a study of the social and psychological implication of the spectrum, so that from a deep understanding of this they can deduce it all for themselves? Mnemonics and rote learning have their place and it would be a betrayal of the students to leave them out.

Comment: And thank you to those who have answered my request.

Comment: *I also teach "how to pass an exam without knowing anything"*.  That's just plain irresponsible teaching!

Comment: It's even more irresponsible not to

Comment: "my job was and is to get students to pass the exam". Regardless of whether they know the material? I weep for this generation.

Comment: I'm talking about University education. Of course (no pun intended) passing the exam involves knowing the material, and the grade achieved depends on how well they know and can use it. The "how to pass without knowing..." is a jokey title for helping to use wit and common sense to their advantage. The skill of the examiner (that was me, too) is to set an exam that takes all that into account, is fair, and allows the grade to be accurately assessed. If they don't pass at all then the initial selection system is at fault The "regardless of whether or not they know the material" is a straw man.

Comment: @HarryWeston `In the real world they have access to all the reference material.` Then I could be a good programmer without understanding languages and algorithms because there's a lot of snippets around the web that often do what I need? Wikipedia, stack exchange  and the like are not an excuse for not knowing things, but should be a stimulus for learning (and maybe teach ...)

Comment: Ah, and about `how do they learn the Resistor Colour Code?` You probably will not be able to believe that you just know one color every two to derive the others. :-)
Memory is important but not alone.

Comment: Thank you Antonio, good points well made, But I do feel so misunderstood. By "In the real world they have access to all the reference material" I was emphasising that in an exam you have no access and need to remember it all. Even the best programmer will need access to language definitions etc at some time, won't get them in an exam (unless the examiner provides them, and in that case the way the Q are set, and the marking scheme, will allow for it).  And the bit about the Resistor Colour Code was a sarcastic reply to those who eschew any rote learning at all. That's it, nothing deeper.

Comment: I don't like this answer. It's focusing on the fact that the asker mentioned mnemonics and completely ignored that they explitly stated that they also accept other easily remembered ways to distinguish them, which could include an easy to understand explanation of what the names actually mean, and perhaps *should*, but the answer is focused on telling the asker what not to teach instead.

Answer (score 1):

An amplifier has an input port, and an output port. A port has two terminals. They should practice to identify the terminal that is **common** to both the input and the output port.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I must agree with Olin's assessment, and think a mnemonic is causing students to just remember an algorithm to solve an exam problem (it happened to me!) instead of truly understanding the task, but I don't find the mnemonic evil and utterly useless.

I'm doing some tutoring on that area as well. As mentioned, while I was studying it myself, I wasn't really thinking about it. But it's really logical when you think about it.
Think of an amplifier as a two-circuit... circuit. You have an input circuit (where you have an input signal generator, for instance), and an output circuit (where you send the amplified signal to the output device - a loudspeaker, for instance).

A transistor has three terminals, or pins - I believe it is safe to think of it this way: one in the input circuit, one in the output circuit, and one that serves as an interface of a kind between the two. In other words, it is shared between the two circuits, and it is **common** to both the input and the output circuit.

As per alephzero's suggestion, another way to look at it would be this: if you "pull out" a transistor from an amplifier schematic, the input and output circuits will have two open connections each. That's four. Since the transistor has only three terminals, and both circuits need to be closed, one of the terminals must be common to both circuits.

So!

CE - The emitter is common - it closes both circuits. The base has the signal generator, and the collector has an output device, for instance.

CB - The base is common - it closes both circuits. Emitter - input, collector - output.

CC - The collector is common - it closes both circuits. Base - input, emitter - output.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like the general approach of this answer, but not the details. An input *circuit* has two connections, not one. Since two input connections plus two output connections make four, and a transistor has only three connections, one of the four has to be "common" - and that one can be either the base, the emitter, or the collector. Details like "usually just a resistor between it and ground" are irrelevant, and possibly confusing to students if they think that such things *must* be part of the complete circuit.

Comment: @alephzero I agree, that makes sense. I tried to simplify it, and I might have overdone it inadvertently. Of course a circuit has two connections, and two plus two equals four. What I meant to say was that, from the perspective of the transistor, one terminal is in the input circuit, one in the output circuit, and the third one is closing both circuits, thus making itself **common** to them. 
But the "interface" part is, I think, a justified simplification, made in order to illustrate the concept.

And regarding the details - they are unnecessary, I agree.

Comment: This is a good answer because it explains what the word "common" means in the names of the circuits. It's "common" in the sense of "shared", not in the sense of "popular and widely used". That understanding alone is the key to recognizing the circuits. That's not a hack.